# How to scale the number of form fields based on user input?

Tags: php, forms

I’m new to PHP and making a website to add an arbitrary number of values in a given base. How would I generate several fields based on a user’s input in a previous field?

Comment: Through a loop? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: is it in same page or next page?

Comment: I haven’t tried much, as I didn’t know where to start. A for loop would have been my first choice, but I don’t know how to add a field at runtime. It is on the same page.

Comment: "how to add a field at runtime" - what do you mean by runtime? PHP renders the data once and then it's done. Do you want to add them solely on client-side? Then you need Javascript

Comment: Sorry, I meant adding something that isn’t there when the page is first loaded. I used the word runtime out of habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple code without any validation will be like this:

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST['count_of_fields'])) {
    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';
    for ($i = 0; $i < (int) $_POST['count_of_fields']; ++$i) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="field[$i]" /><br>';
    }
    echo ' <input type="submit"></form>';
} else {
    echo '
        <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="number" name="count_of_fields">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the original field containing the number? And is there a way to restrict the range of the number?

Comment: Yes, you can check code with restrictions and original field here: https://3v4l.org/SQtvN

Answer (score 1):

Beside the answer from @lis-dev which is generating fields in server side you will have to load the page each time to render the new fields, let's use JavaScript to do that for you without refreshing the page. and yes using mix and max you can put limit also

```js
function generate()
{
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("no").value);
  for(var i =1; i <= value ; i++)
  {
     var input = document.createElement("input");
     var br = document.createElement("br");
     input.type = "text";
     input.placeholder = "I am dynamic field " + i;
     document.getElementById('form').appendChild(input);
     document.getElementById('form').appendChild(br);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>dynamic fields test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
<input id="no" type="text" min="5" max="10" placeholder="Enter no of Fields">
<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="generate()">
<br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```